# Cesium-137 From Fukushima Meltdown

Tags: radiation

I've been reading up on the Fukushima nuclear meltdown and its effects it had on the environment. The iodine-131 initially released from the incident decayed after 8 days, but other isotopes such as cesium-137 and strontium-90 have a half-life of 28.7 and 30.2 years (about 300 years to completely decay).

Apparently, large quanties of cesium-137 were found in neighbouring countries as well as in seafood near Japan.

Now, for something like nuclear isotopes, not having the required knowledge can lead someone to fear something that might be harmless (or confirm some doubts about the issue), hence why I am here.

From my research on scientific websites and different governmental regulations, I found out that food and water in Japan have a legal limit as to how much cesium-137 a food item can contain. Especially since cesium-137 ressembles potassium and therefore being easily taken up by the body, this is worrying.

To my understanding, the way a radioactive isotope creates havoc in the body of an individual is that:

1. It ressembles a normal element we usually consume, like iodine, potassium for cesium-137 and calcium for strontium-90.
2. The body digests it and it is stored in the body.
3. It emits radation for a certain period of time, anywhere from 8 days for Iodine-131 to years for cesium-137.
4. The prolonged radioactivity from these isotopes causes cancerous cells to occur.
5. A tumour or other form of cancer develops.

If this is what happens for isotopes like cesium-137, how can it be possible to eat food or drink water containing ANY cesium whatsoever? Sure, the radiation isn't so bad, but what is important to take into consideration is that this is internal and highly centralized radiation. This is a completely different thing to external radiation.

For my questions about the topic, I would like to know three things (which could really put many doubts to rest).

QUESTIONS

*The first is, is my understanding described above correct?*

*The second is, how does this affect us healthwise? We are stuck with these debris of cesium-137 and strontium-90 for the next 30 or more years, but what effect do they have on us?*

*If someone ingests an atom (or a small amount) of cesium-137, what affect will this have on this person's body?*

*Finally, for someone living in North America, how much of these debris are there, either that got here from the wind, products, food, water, etc.?*

EDIT: If someone knowledgeable on the subject could answer the questions directly (highlighted by means of italics), it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: On Bio we encourage single, specifically targeted questions. Hence, I vote to close because it's too broad. I encourage you to reduce the stack of questions and generate one, or more separate questions.

Comment: @Christiaan Hi Christiaan. The specific questions are clearly listed at the end of the text. The text before that is simply to give the necassary and preliminary information for the questions. On the contrary, I think it adds precision. The questions alone could make the subsequent discussion rather imprecise. I highlighted the questions to make sure they can't be missed. Please do not close the discussion. Thank you.

Comment: If someone knowledgeable on the subject could answer the questions directly (highlighted by means of italics), it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @samseva your last question on effects in North America is quite different and I would suggest that you remove it from this post.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Hi Wysiwyg. I should create a new topic instead?

Comment: @samseva you can but you have to add more details. Moreover, the question is more about environmental science than biology. So I am not sure if that would be considered on-topic, here. You may try posting that question in [earthscience.se] with some relevant additions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP never corrected the problems pointed out in other comments (multiple questions, some of which are seem to be off-topic as asking for medical advice).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the question has been accurately answered by @davidblomstrom, however regarding the internal exposure to of cesium-137, through ingestion or inhalation, allows the radioactive material to be distributed in the soft tissues, especially muscle tissue, exposing these tissues to the beta particles and gamma radiation and increasing cancer risk.

Also due to the consistency of Cs-137, it comes as a crystalline powder (due to its property of binding with chlorides) which makes it "easier" to be distributed after a nuclear fallout.

> If the lead containers of Cs-137 are opened, the substance inside looks like a white powder and may glow. Cs-137 from nuclear accidents or atomic bomb explosions cannot be seen and will be present in dust and debris from fallout. [read more](http://healthvermont.gov/emerg/drill/dirtybomb/facts-about-cesium137.aspx)

*Sources*

1. "Cesium-137." Vermont Department of Health. Vermont Department of Health. Web. 31 Jan. 2016. http://healthvermont.gov/emerg/drill/dirtybomb/facts-about-cesium137.aspx.
2. Albertini, Dr. R. "Cesium." University of Vermont, 2002. Web. 31 Jan. 2016. http://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/toxprofiles/tp157-c3.pdf.